# Get a foreign key field when using values and annotate

Tags: python, django

I have this model:

```
class Donation(models.Model):
    amount = models.IntegerField()
    receipt = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=True)
    donation_date = models.DateTimeField()
    donator = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='donation_donator', blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    validation_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
```

and then this view:

```
def report(request, month=None):
    datafilter = Q()
    datafilter = datafilter & Q(donation_date__month=month)

    top_donors_month = Donation.objects.values('donator').annotate(Sum('amount')).order_by('-amount__sum').filter(datafilter)
    top_donors_all = Donation.objects.values('donator').annotate(Sum('amount')).order_by('-amount__sum')
```

basically it returns a list of donator-total_amount_donated relationship. but the query returns a dict like so:

```
[{'donator' : 3, 'amount_sum' : 5200}, {'donator' : 2, 'amount_sum' : 1200}, {.....}]
```

where 3,2,1.. etc. are donator pks. how can i access 3's name instead?

e.g.

```
[{'donator' : user1, 'amount_sum' : 5200}, {'donator' : user2, 'amount_sum' : 1200}, {.....}]
```

Comment: You mean `.values('donator__first_name')` ?

Comment: Yup. damn i'm being careless again. i kept trying donator__name. where as the model doesnt have that field. ._. thanks alot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of donator you have to get values as donator__first_name.

Try as below,

```
top_donors_month = Donation.objects.values('donator__first_name').annotate(Sum('amount')).order_by('-amount__sum').filter(datafilter)
top_donors_all = Donation.objects.values('donator__first_name').annotate(Sum('amount')).order_by('-amount__sum')
```

Comment: Yup. damn i'm being careless again. i kept trying donator__name. where as the model doesnt have that field. ._. thanks alot.